# how do i read values returned by SP

Tags: c#, sql

in one of my projects i Have to read the value returned by following procedure in a TextBox using C#.

can anyone plz write the code to read @a in a TextBox returned by following procedure using c#??

```
create procedure [dbo].[Test]    
as    
declare    
@a numeric(5)    
begin    
set @a = (select COUNT(*) from Emp);    
return @a   
end
```

I Have tried this

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=acc;uid=sa;pwd=fantastic");
cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "Test";
Int32 i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
```

Comment: What I have tried i have edited in my question plzz read

Comment: And what didn't work? Did you get errors? Exceptions? What did happen that you didn't expect (or what didn't happen that you did)?

Comment: I'm not getting the actual no. I'm getting zero while count(*) is 23

Comment: Oded how can I Write sql in a Coding format as you edited my sql

Comment: Like all code - indent it 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-- partially copy-pasted, most of it out of the head, but try it:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("test", con);
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParamter returnVal = new SqlParameter("RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
returnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
com.Parameters.Add(returnVal);
com.Connection.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
int A = returnVal.value;
con.Close();
```

ExecuteScalar: "Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query."
You're returning a returnvalue, not a field. If you want to use the Scalar, you need to edit your Stored Procedure to actually return a field like so:

```
create procedure [dbo].[Test] 
as 
begin 

select (select COUNT(*) from Emp)

end
```

Comment: riffnl can you plzz make it according to what I have tried mentioned in my question???/

Comment: Thanks riffnl it worked. Thanks alot

Comment: no i my project i must have to get count(*) in a declared parameter.. and your above mentioned coding did that.. thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a return parameter (see the [answer of riffnl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10244199/121309)) or change the "return" in your sp to "select".

ExecuteScalar doesn't catch the return value, only the first `select`ed value.